# Solr update log

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.10.4, but I am in trouble understanding the meaning of the log.

In the log of path =/update, what does the meaning of the two numbers printed at the end of the line mean?

ex)
`2018-12-03 20: 0 6: 30.969; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [sample_index] webapp=/solr path=/ update params={version=2.2} {commit=} 0 13500`

what's mean '0 13500' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is the status of the request - 0 means that everything went as planned. The second number is the QTime - i.e. how long time the query took. In this case the commit took 13.5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  
I understood two numbers.